# Calling member's overloaded << operator in C++

Tags: c++, class, overloading, operator-keyword, member

The following raises a compile-time error. I'm not sure how to call one objects
overloaded operator << within another objects << operator? If anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong, that'd be really helpful .Thanks for your time!

card.cpp:

```
#include "card.h"
#include <iostream>

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, Card &cCard)
{
    out << cCard.getValueString() 
        << " OF " 
        << cCard.getSuitString() 
        << "S\n";
    return out;
}

string Card::getValueString()
{
    Value value = getValue();
    switch(value) 
    {
        case TWO:           return "TWO";
        case THREE:         return "THREE"; 
        case FOUR:          return "FOUR"; 
        case FIVE:          return "FIVE";
        case SIX:           return "SIX";
        case SEVEN:         return "SEVEN";
        case EIGHT:         return "EIGHT";
        case NINE:          return "NINE";
        case TEN:           return "TEN";
        case JACK:          return "JACK";
        case QUEEN:         return "QUEEN";
        case KING:          return "KING";
        case ACE:           return "ACE"; 
        case NONE_VALUE:    return "NONE_VALUE";
        default:            return "UNKNOWN VALUE";  
    };
}

string Card::getSuitString()
{
    Suit suit = getSuit();
    switch(suit) 
    {
        case SPADE:         return "SPADE";
        case HEART:         return "HEART"; 
        case CLUB:          return "CLUB"; 
        case DIAMOND:       return "DIAMOND";
        case NONE_SUIT:     return "NONE_SUIT";
        default:            return "UNKNOWN SUIT";
    };
}
```

card.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 enum Suit  { 
                SPADE, 
                HEART, 
                CLUB, 
                DIAMOND,
                NONE_SUIT 
            };

 enum Value  { 
                TWO=2, 
                THREE, 
                FOUR, 
                FIVE,
                SIX,
                SEVEN,
                EIGHT,
                NINE,
                TEN,
                JACK,
                QUEEN,
                KING,
                ACE, 
                NONE_VALUE
            };

    class Card
    {

        public:
            Card() : m_suit(NONE_SUIT), m_value(NONE_VALUE) { };
            Card(Suit suit, Value value) : m_suit(suit), m_value(value) { };
            Value getValue() { return m_value; };
            Suit getSuit() { return m_suit; };
            void setValue(Value value) { m_value = value; };
            void setSuit(Suit suit) { m_suit = suit; };
            string getValueString();
            string getSuitString();
            friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, Card &cCard);
        private:
            Suit m_suit;
            Value m_value;      
    };
```

hand.cpp:

```
#include "hand.h"
#include "card.h"

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, Card &cCard);

Hand::Hand() 
{

}

Card Hand::getCard(int cardIndex) 
{
    if(cardIndex == 0 || cardIndex == 1)
    {
        return cards[cardIndex];
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Card index out of bounds.\n";
    }

    return Card(NONE_SUIT, NONE_VALUE);
}

void Hand::setCard(int cardIndex, Suit suit, Value value)
{
    if(cardIndex == 0 || cardIndex == 1)
    {
        cards[cardIndex].setValue(value);
        cards[cardIndex].setSuit(suit);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Card index out of bounds.\n";
    }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, Hand &cHand)
{
    out << cHand.getCard(0) 
        << "\n"
        << cHand.getCard(1);
    return out;
}
```

hand.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "card.h"
using namespace std;

class Hand
{
    public:
        Hand();
        void setCard(int cardIndex, Suit suit, Value value);
        Card getCard(int cardIndex);
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, Hand &cHand);
    private:
        Card cards[2];      
};
```

The error is the following:

hand.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Hand&)’:
hand.cpp:40: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘out << ((Hand*)cHand)->Hand::getCard(0)’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:112: note: candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:121: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:131: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:169: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:173: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:177: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/ostream.tcc:92: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:184: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/ostream.tcc:106: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:195: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:204: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:208: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:213: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:217: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:225: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:229: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/ostream.tcc:120: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
hand.cpp:4: note:                 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Card&)
hand.cpp:38: note:                 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Hand&)

Any ideas on what Im missing?

Comment: From what I can see, that looks OK - so either the problem is in the "..." sections that you left out, or you haven't explained very well what's going wrong (in other words, something else is going wrong than "it doesn't compile" - for example you get no output, because you have no flush on the `cout` line - adding an `endl` may solve that).

Comment: The most likely thing I can guess is either missing `std::`s, missing headers, or no semicolons after the classes: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ccead1b951d7ebef1db70f3d9bc387f5-3b440a87a52fe2ae7c853c82f4c5144f

Comment: Don't see much here.  You forgot the `;` at the ends of class definitions?  `info` isn't a member of `A`?  You literally used `...`?

Comment: Your fake code is useless in helping us diagnose your problem. Please present your actual code. All of it.

Answer (score 4):

Your `operator <<` functions should take the right hand side argument by const reference. It's telling you that it can't bind the temporary returned by `getCard` to the non-const reference argument of the operator.

The incredibly long error message is because there are so incredibly many overloads of `<<` in scope at any one time, and the compiler is listing all of them as, "I tried this one but it didn't work."